# Can dictionaries be stored in globalDict?

Tags: python, game-engine

In the Blender API docs, it says only

> Python built in types such as int/string/bool/float/tuples/lists can be saved, GameObjects, Actuators etc will not work as expected.

No mention is made of whether dictionaries can be stored.

My own tests seem to indicate it is possible, and I have not yet had any Marshalling or other exceptions raised, but I would like to know if it is actually supported, or if I would be better off building an alternate implementation that does not require storing dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is only an example of types -

> Python **built in types** *such as* int/string/bool/float/tuples/lists **can be saved**,

while it does not give a complete list of built-in types, a dictionary is a built-in python type so does belong to that list of types. While an int and float may be simpler types, a list or tuple would be equal to a dictionary in this context.

> GameObjects, Actuators etc will not work as expected.

This indicates the types defined by blender, most of which are not *fully* implemented the way that the python built-in types are, will not work as expected.

As the first line states **can be saved** which also implies being loaded back between games, I would expect the exact criteria to be types that are [picklable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-picklable), which would also mean that the items in the dictionary must also be built-in types, not blender types. Of course if you aren't actually saving the globalDict between games and just want to use it during game play then you should find these restrictions to be irrelevant.

Comment: That was my assumption, however it struck me as odd that they would mention all the basic data types except for dicts

Comment: Well they didn't list complex numbers, sets, bytes, bytearrays. To me it looks like an "off the top of my head" list rather than an exact researched list.

Comment: Everything that can be marshalled (see Python docs) can be placed into global dict without breaking the load/save operations of the load/save actuators. Do not confuse it with "pickable" - pickle supports more types, but is not used here.